How to get which bone effects which mesh in Skeleton3D?
I have multiple meshes binded to a single Skeleton3D as such:

and each mesh is completely weight painted to only one bone

Given a mesh, How do I get the bone(s) in Skeleton3D which have weight paint on it and ignore those bones which have no weight on that mesh?
